# TailwindCSS breakpoints defined in the config file differ from what I am experiencing

Tags: css, tailwind-css, breakpoints

I am using Next.js with TailwindCSS to build a website. The breakpoints defined in the tailwind.config.js and the [website](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design) do not correspond to what I am experiencing on my screen. So I tested it by changing the background color for each breakpoint and writing down the width at which the color would change. I used the Chrome dev tools responsive screen to check the width in pixels. Why do my breakpoints differ from the tailwind.config.js file? Am I missing something?

tailwind.config.js:

```
screens: {
      sm: '640px',
      md: '768px',
      lg: '1024px',
      xl: '1280px',
      '2xl': '1536px',
    },
```

My code:

```
<section className="bg-green-500 sm:bg-purple-500 md:bg-red-500 lg:bg-orange-500 xl:bg-blue-500 2xl:bg-black h-[100vh] relative">
```

My breakpoints:

```
      sm: '512px',
      md: '615px',
      lg: '820px',
      xl: '1024px',
     '2xl': '1229px',
```

Answer (score 0):

try clearing your browser cache file using the empty cache and hard-reload option, as your chrome could be showing you some fragment from the previous code,

to do the empty cache & hard reload simply hold down the refresh button, till its shows you the below image[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Could it be a problem with my Chrome settings? I just tested it on Safari and it corresponds to the tailwind.config.js breakpoints!

Comment: probably it may be , try to restore your chrome settings